# Solving a quadratic program with one equality constraint

Tags: matrices, optimization, inverse, constraints, quadratic-programming

Let $d,n$ be positive integers, $(\mu_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}$ and $(\eta_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}$ some scalars, and  define

$$ A := \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_i y_i y_i^T, \qquad c := \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \eta_i y_i $$

for some vectors $y_i \in  \mathbb{R}^d$.
Finally, let $\varepsilon>0$. I wish to solve the following optimization problem :
\begin{aligned}
&\displaystyle \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} \frac{1}{2}x^TAx \\
&\text{such that} \text{  } x^Tc=\varepsilon
\end{aligned}

I have defined the corresponding Lagrangian

$$L\left(x,\lambda\right)=\frac{1}{2}x^TAx-\lambda(x^Tc-\varepsilon)$$

The condition $\nabla_x L\left(x,\lambda\right) = 0$ yields $Ax=\lambda c$. When $A$ is invertible, $x$ can be expressed as $x=\lambda A^{-1}c$ and the optimization problem can then be straightforwardly solved : the constraint along with $Ax=\lambda c$ implies $x^TAx=\lambda\varepsilon$. We can then identify $\lambda$ by plugging $x=\lambda A^{-1}c$ in the previous equation and find the value of $\frac{1}{2}x^TAx$   (I get that the minimum equals $\frac{\varepsilon^2}{2c^TA^{-1}c}$).

What happens when $A$ is **not** invertible? Can the quadratic program still be solved explicitly in a similar way? If not, can we at least find an approximate solution?

**EDIT** : I may have part of an answer but I am not sure it is entirely correct.

- If $c \in \operatorname{Col}(A) $ where $\operatorname{Col}(A)$ is the vector space spanned by the columns of $A$, then $x=\lambda A^+c$ where $A^+$ is the moore-penrose pseudoinverse of $A$ is a solution of $Ax=\lambda c$. In fact, for $x^*=\lambda^* A^+c$ with $\lambda^*=\frac{\varepsilon}{c^TA^{+}c}$ (assuming that the denominator is non zero...), we have $\nabla_x L\left(x^*,\lambda^*\right) = 0$ and ${x^*}^Tc=\varepsilon$. Isn't this enough to ensure that this $x^*$ is an optimal solution of my problem in this case ?
- if $c \notin \operatorname{Col}(A)$, $Ax=\lambda c$ yields $\lambda=0$ which implies that $x^TAx=0$. Does that mean that the minimum is $0$ in this case ?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1793370/339790)

Comment: Take a look at the link above.  This boils down to linear algebra.  Note that you might have infinitely many minimizers

Comment: Also, you can write $x_d$ in terms of $x_1, \dots, x_{d-1}$ and then solve the unconstrained QP in $d-1$ variables

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo isn't the matrix Q in the link you sent (which would correspond to A in my case) assumed to be invertible, or did I misunderstand something ?

Comment: And who mentioned inverting matrices? Just use Gaussian elimination

Comment: The solution in the link depends on $Q^-1$. Could you explain what you mean by using gaussian elimination here ?

Comment: Do you want a closed-form solution?  What if there are infinitely many solutions? In that case, you might want the solution closest to the origin, for example.  You can solve the linear system (take a look at the linked question) using Gaussian elimination and obtain the parametrization of the solution set.

Comment: I only care about the value of the minimum, so even if there are infinitely many solutions, as long as the minimum they achieve is the same I'm good (I think that's the case when $c$ is in the range of $A$ ; if I'm not mistaken the solutions are then of the form $x_0+\lambda A^+c$ for some $x_0 \in \operatorname{ker}(A)$ and $\lambda=\frac{\varepsilon}{c^TA^+c}$, and for all these solutions the value of $x^TAx$ is the same). I'll look deeper into the linked question, thank you.

Comment: Am I mistaken or wouldn't gaussian elimination be of use when I have an explicit matrix A and an explicit vector c at my disposal ? I'm interested in a theoretical result that works for any choice of A and c.

Comment: Have you considered adding a regularisation term to the cost function?

Comment: I am not really familiar with standard optimization techniques (as you can probably tell). Why would adding a regularisation term be helpful ?

Comment: If you add $\gamma \|x\|_2^2$ to the cost function, you might make the matrix invertible

Comment: You should mention that $n < d$

Comment: I'm not assuming $n < d$ ; in fact most of the time it's the opposite in practice for my use case. Does my analysis fail when we don't have $n < d$ ?

Comment: If $n > d$, assuming that the $y$ vectors are sufficiently "spread out", I would expect $A$ to be invertible.

Comment: yeah, I think most of the time it will be. I just need to be thorough because it can still be non-invertible depending on the setup, as no assumptions are made on the vectors $y_i$.