# Find the Minimum of: $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2+\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}g_{j-i}a_i a_j+\sum_{i=1}^n q_i a_i$

Tags: inequality, optimization, convex-optimization, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, operations-research

I'm confused with the following problem when doing my research.

Given $g_i,i=1,2,..,n-1$ and $q_i,i=1,2,..,n$, find the minimum of:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2+\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}g_{j-i}a_i a_j+\sum_{i=1}^n q_i a_i$$

subject to $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i=1,a_i \geq 0$$

If necessary, we can assume the sign of $g_i$ and $q_i$(such as $g_i<0,q_i>0$ for all i) and the value of $|g_i|$ and $|q_i|$ can be sufficiently small for all i. Is there a way to find the closed-form solution of $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ when the target is minimized? Some approximate methods and some solutions with specific $q_i$ and $g_i$ are also of great help. I would be grateful if there is any hint.

Comment: $a_i \geq 0$ makes it ugly. Otherwise it would be a neat quadratic expression.

Comment: In fact, $a_i<0$  is kind of counter-intuitive  for us. If we do remove the restriction, is there a closed-form solution for the new problem?

Comment: Isn't this a QP?  How do you know it's convex?

Comment: @17dj Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1793526/339790)

Answer (score 3):

*Please see the discussion under the actual question. There, a closed-form solution for the question without nonnegativity restrictions on the $\{a_i\}$ was asked for, which is given here. *

I would go with a Discrete Fourier Transformation. Let a matrix $U$ with $u_{ j k} =\exp (i (j-1) (k-1) 2 \pi / n)$, then $U^\dagger U = n I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.

The given problem is to minimize, where $a$ and $q$ are vectors and $G$ is a matrix given by the problem definition
$$
a^T G a +  a^T q
$$

Let vectors $b = U a$ and $r = U q$, and the matrix $H = \frac{1}{n} U G U^\dagger$. $G$ is of Toeplitz structure, so $H$ will not be diagonal (which would be the case for a circulant matrix $G$).
Then equivalently minimize

$$
b^T H b +  b^T r
$$

Now since $b_1 = \sum_i a_i = 1$, this can be written explicitely

$$h_{11} + b_1 r_ 1+ \sum_{j=2}^n  (h_{1 j} + h_{j 1} + r_j) b_j  + \sum_{j, k=2}^n  h_{j k } b_j b_k$$

and the condition $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i=1$ is already included. Now minimizing w.r.t. the $b_j$ gives $n-1$ linear equations (where $j = 2 \dots n$)

$$ (h_{1 j} + h_{j 1}  + r_j)  + \sum_{k=2}^n  (h_{k j} + h_{j k}) b_k = 0 $$

Writing this in compact form, with  $(n-1)$-dimensional vectors  and an $(n-1)\times (n-1)$-dimensional matrix, where the first index is missing,  denoted by bars
$$ \bar c + \bar F \bar b = \bar 0$$ or

$$a = \frac1n U^\dagger \left(1 \atop \bar b \right) =  \frac1n U^\dagger \left(1 \atop - {\bar F}^{-1} \bar c \right)  $$

as a closed solution for an extremal point, where it has to be checked whether this is a minimum.

Comment: Your answer also does not seem to account for the nonnegativity of $a$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wonder if $q_i$ and $p_i$ are sufficiently small compared to $\frac{1}{n}$, can we make the assumption that $a_i \geq 0$ in your solution ?  It seems that the optimal choice of $a$ is around ($\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n},...,\frac{1}{n}$)

Comment: @17dj I couldn't really say if, and under which circumstances, the solution exhibits nonnegative $a_i$. This dives into a constrained quadratic optimization problem. Did you try with some experimental values for the $g_i$ and $q_i$ ?

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Please see the discussion under the actual question. There, a closed-form solution for the question without nonnegativity restrictions on the $a_i$ was asked for.

Answer (score 3):

Relaxing the condition $a_i \ge 0$ as suggested in the question discussion, with

$$
M = \left(\matrix{
1&g_1&g_2&g_3&\cdots&g_n\\
0&1&g_1&g_2& \cdots&g_{n-1}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&g_1\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&1
}\right)
$$

we have

$$
L(a,\lambda) = a^T\cdot M\cdot a+a^T\cdot q - \lambda (a^T \cdot \hat 1 - 1)
$$

with $\hat 1 = (1,\cdots,1)^T$. Also

$$
\nabla L = 2M\cdot a+q-\lambda \hat 1 = 0
$$

then the stationary point is determined as

$$
a^* = \frac 12M^{-1}\cdot(\lambda \hat 1-q)
$$

$M^{-1} = \text{adj}(M)$ because $\det (M)=1$ now making

$$
\hat 1^T\cdot a^* = \frac 12 \hat 1^T\cdot\text{adj}(M)\cdot(\lambda \hat 1-q)=1
$$

and then

$$
\lambda = \frac{1+\frac 12 \hat 1^T\cdot\text{adj}(M)\cdot q}{\frac 12 \hat 1^T\cdot\text{adj}(M)\cdot \hat 1}
$$

and substituting into $a^*$ we obtain the stationary point.

Comment: You did not include the constraint.

Comment: Thanks. I will introduce it asap!

Comment: Already fixed. I hope!

Comment: Nice! I think you can make some simplifications when you plug into $a^*$

Comment: Actually, how do you account for the nonnegativity of the $a_i$'s?

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Do you mean the nonnegativity of $a$? If so, I was wondering the same thing.

Comment: @prubin I guess the OP may be okay with letting go of the nonnegativity constraint.